# std::vector vs std::list for insertion frequency and dynamic size

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector, shared-memory

Consider the case where I've to add a random number of items to a container i.e. the size of the container cannot be predicted, the frequency of the insertion is high ,and the insertion should be at the end of the container, additional to that I want to remove an element with almost a constant time.

**Note:** I want also to use the list or the vector in the shared memory.

So in this case, which is better to use std::vector or std::list?

Comment: Where are the elements that have to get removed? But ultimately my answer to nearly all of these questions is use vector as default and make a 2nd version with the list to compare with if you're not sure. Aka PROFILE IT!

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl ,the elements can be at any place. I need random access.
Also I saw that everytime I need to add element to the vector, it has to be allocated again with a new size, which doesn't apply for the list.

Comment: You can also consider std::deque.

Comment: Do you need other elements to be at the same order after removing one element?

Comment: No, I don't need that, I read about the dequeue, they said 

For operations that involve frequent insertion or removals of elements at positions other than the beginning or the end, deques perform worse and have less consistent iterators and references than lists and forward lists.

Comment: @HA-AS: no sane std::vector<> implementation will allocate each time a value is added. Many implementations allocate the double amount of memory that is needed if no space is left. So it needs a long time before the next re-allocation is needed. This gives a std::vector<> a quite good performance for adding elements.
Next the cache-locality of a std::vector is much better than that of a list. So when iterating over the vector the CPU does not suffer from as much cache misses as it does when iterating over a list where the elements are spread over the memory over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the clarification in the comments, the answer is `std::vector`.  This is not surprising, as `std::list` is rarely the best container for a job.

Adding elements to the end is amortized constant time, and removing an element at a random index is as fast as a `list`, as finding elements in a `list` typically takes longer than deleting them from a `vector`.

Note that if order does not matter, you can swap an arbitrary element of a `vector` with the end one, then `pop_back` for constant-time random-access erase.

If you regularly iterate over the container, you can `remove_if` - `erase` in order to erase elements efficiently at the same time.  If erasure happens at a different time than iteration, marking elements as 'to be erased' then erasing them on the next iteration can keep things sane.

Another container to consider if the element order does not matter is `unordered_set`.

Comment: If the objects are expensive to `move`, a vector of `unique_ptr` can sometimes also be a good idea. `.reset()`ing can be used to mark for later removal.

Comment: If order does not matter, `std::partition` - `erase` is the multi removal equivalent of `swap` - `pop_back`.